# how to filter on compound column in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui

Is it possible to custom filter on compound column in Kendo Grid?

This is my Dojo [http://dojo.telerik.com/AZUra/4] 
Here at the Status column,which is a compound column by the template, I want to have custom filter for both fields: the 'art' and 'date time' field ( currently I am giving only the 'art' field to filter). How could I achieve to have custom filtering. That is either of the field the user will input as a filter. I've edited my question and added more details too. Thanks
 [reference for compound column:](https://onabai.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/kendoui-grid-with-composed-cell/)

Comment: Could you define what a compund column is to you? Better yet. Show us a distince complete example, which reproduces your problem!

Comment: @Marco .This is my Dojo [http://dojo.telerik.com/AZUra/4] Here at the Status column,which is a compound column, I want to have custom filter for both field, the 'art' and 'date time' field ( currently I am giving only the 'art' field to filter). How could I achieve to have custom filtering. That is either of the filed the user will input as a filter. I've edited my question and added more details too. Thanks